# Drupal 7 - Banner Image

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, field

I want to access a field I created for an image. I have hidden the field so it doesn't appear in the regular `print render($page['content']);` function.

If I print the $page variable I can see my custom field under. `[field_associated_image]`

I have seen examples relating to the [views module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13205/add-a-unique-banner-image-to-each-page) but this seems overcomplicated for what I'm trying to acheive.

This might seem like a simple question but I can't seem to find a simple answer for this online.

**$page array**

```
[content] => Array
        (
            [system_main] => Array
                (
                    [nodes] => Array
                        (
                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [#pre_render] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => _field_extra_fields_pre_render
                                        )

                                    [#entity_type] => node
                                    [#bundle] => page
                                    [#view_mode] => full
                                    [#theme] => node
                                    [#node] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [vid] => 2
                                            [uid] => 1
                                            [title] => Home
                                            [log] => 
                                            [status] => 1
                                            [comment] => 1
                                            [promote] => 0
                                            [sticky] => 0
                                            [nid] => 2
                                            [type] => page
                                            [language] => und
                                            [created] => 1386864773
                                            [changed] => 1386886093
                                            [tnid] => 0
                                            [translate] => 0
                                            [revision_timestamp] => 1386886093
                                            [revision_uid] => 1
                                            [body] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [und] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [value] => 
Test

                                                                    [summary] => 
                                                                    [format] => filtered_html
                                                                    [safe_value] => 
Test

                                                                    [safe_summary] => 
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [field_associated_image] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [und] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [fid] => 5
                                                                    [alt] => 
                                                                    [title] => 
                                                                    [width] => 976
                                                                    [height] => 438
                                                                    [uid] => 1
                                                                    [filename] => home-banner.jpg
                                                                    [uri] => public://home-banner_0.jpg
                                                                    [filemime] => image/jpeg
                                                                    [filesize] => 85851
                                                                    [status] => 1
                                                                    [timestamp] => 1386886093
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [name] => admin
                                            [picture] => 0
                                            [data] => b:0;
                                            [entity_view_prepared] => 1
                                        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to create a custom module to access the field

```
function custom_field_attach_view_alter(&$output, $context) {
  $node = $context['entity'];
  $instances = _field_invoke_get_instances('node', $node->type, array('default' => TRUE, 'deleted' => FALSE));
  foreach ($instances as $field_name => $instance) {
    if ($instance['field_name']=="your_field_name") {

      $display = field_get_display($instance, 'full', $node);
      // Do not add field that is hidden in current display.
      if ($display['type'] == 'hidden') {
        continue;
      }
      // Load field settings.
      $field = field_info_field($field_name);

      $output[$field_name] = array(
        '#theme' => 'field',
        '#title' => $instance['label'],
        '#label_display' => 'hidden',
        '#field_type' => $field['type'],
        '#field_name' => $field_name,
        '#bundle' => $node->type,
        '#object' => $node,
        '#items' => array(1),
        '#entity_type' => 'node',
        '#weight' => $display['weight'],
        0 => array('#markup' => $text),
      );
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm not sure how I would use this function? I see the function takes two parameters output and context.

Comment: the function will automatically run in a custom module